# Insert Table parameter to 2 different tables within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, cursor

I have a table-valued parameter `@supplierData` in a stored procedure which has columns as follows

```
sName | sLocation | currYearExpt | currYearImpt | prevYearExpt | prevYearImpt
----------
XXX   | USA       | 1000         | 2000         | 1000         | 2050
YYY   | U.K       | 8000         | 12000        | 10000        | 29000
```

The table needs to be inserted to the below 2 tables

`SUPPLIER` table:

```
sId        | sName | sLocation |
(Identity) |       |           |
----------
 1         | XXX   | USA       |
 2         | YYY   | U.K       |
```

and

`SUPPLIERRECORD` table:

```
YearId | sId | currYearExpt | currYearImpt | prevYearExpt | prevYearImpt|
----------
 1     | 1   | 1000         | 2000         | 1000         | 2050        |
 2     | 2   | 8000         | 12000        | 10000        | 29000       |
```

Where in the 2nd table is having reference to the `sId` created as part of the same stored procedure execution.

Should I insert record by record from `@supplierData` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the DENSE_RANK function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) with OVER to specify the order and a partitioning criteria. So you'll get numeric IDs for your suppliers. You could insert them into a table parameter first and than use this for your two INSERTs

Comment: why DENSE_RANK needed here ?

Comment: It is not completely clear but I'd assume, that the originally posted lines are just examples. I'd assume that there are multiple rows for each supplier. DENSE_RANK with a PARTITION BY sName,sLocation would create distinct "IDs" for the suppliers...

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. Let use `insert into select` or `select into`, they are created to do the kind of this:

```
DECLARE @supplierData TABLE
(
  sName nvarchar(50),
  sLocation nvarchar(50),
  currYearExpt int,
  currYearImpt int,
  prevYearExpt int,
  prevYearImpt int
);

DECLARE @SUPPLIER TABLE
(
  sId int,
  sName nvarchar(50),
  sLocation nvarchar(50)
);
insert into @SUPPLIER values(1,'XXX','USA');
insert into @SUPPLIER values(2,'YYY','U.K');

DECLARE @SUPPLIERRECORD TABLE
(
  YearId int,
  sId int,
  currYearExpt int,
  currYearImpt int,
  prevYearExpt int,
  prevYearImpt int
);
insert into @SUPPLIERRECORD values(1,1,1000,2000,1000,2050);     
insert into @SUPPLIERRECORD values(2,2,8000,12000,10000,29000);

insert into @supplierData
select a.sName, a.sLocation, b.currYearExpt, b.currYearImpt, b.prevYearExpt, b.prevYearImpt
from @SUPPLIER a inner join @SUPPLIERRECORD b on a.sId = b.sId

select * from @supplierData
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm quite sure that the originally posted values are just examples. The callenge'd be to achieve this with many rows and with multiple rows per supplier. Look at my answer about DENSE_RANK

Comment: Yes the values are just samples, the sId is identity and created when the Supplier entry is added. The same value needs to be inserted into SupplierRecord table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `insert into .. select from` construct like below

```
insert into SUPPLIER(sName , sLocation)
select sName , sLocation 
from @supplierData;

insert into SUPPLIERRECORD (currYearExpt , currYearImpt , prevYearExpt , prevYearImpt)
select currYearExpt , currYearImpt , prevYearExpt , prevYearImpt
from @supplierData;
```

Comment: This will not cover the (quite probable) issue of multiple rows per supplier/years. Look at my answer about DENSE_RANK